# How do I make python react to something in the console (without pressing enter)

Tags: python, python-turtle, python-os

I am making a game in python, but I want python to react to the W,A,S,D keys without pressing enter. Like:

If w in console:
Y_pos = Y_pos + 1

If you guys could tell me how to do that then that would be a big help

Comment: You can try this module: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: I think this answers your question: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/how-to-detect-key-presses)

Comment: It does, but it asked me to root Linux, how do I do that?

Comment: Its mentioned in the docs of `keyboard` module that it requires sudo privilege. You can try with https://sshkeyboard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, which doesn't require sudo privilege as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some of the answers [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556907/continually-prompting-user-for-input-in-python) In general, you need an infinite `while` loop that will accept the user input. Don't forget an exit condition, otherwise you'll have to kill the program to end it.

If you're doing this for practice, kudos. But, in case you're focused on making a working game, not on python itself, may I suggest [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) engine for starters?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe keyboard package is what you need.
Various usages for your information.

[keyboard usages](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/python+get+keyboard+press)

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding some more explanation and code.

Comment: Package keyboard needs to be run in a root privilege. But my local env was restricted as normal user, only have remote server with root privilege. Sorry for the answer without validation.